# How to add background image to pdf Document using Itext?

Tags: java, itext

I want to add background image to PDF document using IText and that should be printable in A4 Size paper.

I looked at [How to insert a image under the text as a pdf background using iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794604/how-to-insert-a-image-under-the-text-as-a-pdf-background-using-itext) but some how i am not convinced.

Thank You!!

EDIT : I dont have a PDF i am creating it, while creating it i want add it as one of the attribute.

Comment: here is a sample source code, where documents is first created, then watermark is added, with comments: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=119

Comment: Is there any other way to specify the background image without using stamper, like we add labels

Comment: You can also use page event, it was described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677207/itext-how-do-i-insert-background-image-in-the-same-document-to-be-flushed-to-r look at answer with PdfPageEventHelper